# Grails - No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:

Tags: grails, jdbc

My Grails web-app uses an ad-hoc library called ws-client-1.0.2.jar, this library depends on Oracle (com.oracle.ojdbc14:10.2.0.3.0).
Because Grails repository doesn't contain that Oracle driver, I removed it from DataSource.groovy and I've manually grabbed its jar putting it under lib/ folder. Then, my lib/ contains:

[image: lib/ folder![][1]]

I ran `grails compile --refresh-dependencies` and it works fine.
Then, I started my app with `grails run-app` and everytime I get this error:

```
Class: java.sql.SQLException
Message: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@svildb.dev:1538:QUAT
```

The same happens when I run the unit tests `grails run test-app`

Why the ojdbc driver is not loaded despite it is under lib/ folder?

Comment: I wonder if the 14 in "ojdbc14" refers to the JDK its written to.  I'd expect to see ojdbc6 or ojdbc7, matching the JDK you deploy to.  If you deploy on Tomcat 7.x or higher, it's looking for JDBC JARs in the server /lib, not your WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: you have removed it from the build and not the datasource, right?  could you please also provide the driver, dialect and the connectionstring from your datasource config?

Comment: @duffymo my JDK is: java version "1.7.0_55".

Comment: I'm very glad.  Well done!

Comment: @nicolimo86 You may want to consider a build tool like [gradle](https://gradle.org/) to handle library dependencies.

Comment: You'd still have to know to tell Gradle what the right version needs to be.  It feels like one more thing to be ignorant of.  Better to get this working on your own first, in my view.

Comment: @duffymo you are right again. Because now the error is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0. But I tought it was a different problem and I didn't write it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to this [post](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Getting-a-database-connection-with-BasicDataSource-and-GrabConfig-systemClassloader-true-td5710430.html):

Thanks to [@Duffymo](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Getting-a-database-connection-with-BasicDataSource-and-GrabConfig-systemClassloader-true-td5710430.html)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495560/grails-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcoraclethin?noredirect=1#comment47150070_29495560) I downloaded the right Oracle's ojdbc driver:

1. I downloaded the ojdbc7.jar from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html)
2. I put it under the lib/ folder.

After that, in the library ws-client-1.0.2.jar which rely on Oracle ojdbc I changed the way I instantiate the Sql object:

**BEFORE**

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
...
db={ Sql.newInstance(
      'jdbc:oracle:thin:@vbsvildb.dev:1538:QUAT',
      'user',
      'password',
      'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
    )
}
```

**AFTER**

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
...
/* Setting connection details */
BasicDataSource bdsQUAT = new BasicDataSource()
bdsQUAT.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@svildb.dev:1538:QUAT")
bdsQUAT.setUsername("user")
bdsQUAT.setPassword("password")
bdsQUAT.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")
/* Getting connection to DB */
db=Sql.newInstance(bdsQUAT.getConnection())
```

I built the library again and I got a new ws-client-1.0.2.jar, then I copied it to my grails project under lib/ folder.
Now if I run `grails test-app` everything work!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@Duffymo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/37213/duffymo)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495560/grails-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcoraclethin?noredirect=1#comment47150070_29495560) I got some progress:

1. I downloaded the ojdbc7.jar from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html)
2. I put it under the lib/ folder.

Comment: I prefer to wait a bit more, because that is not a complete solution to the problem.

Comment: @ChrisLoonam ok I edited it. I also added this partial solution to the post where I put the final solution. Should I delete this post?